# Is it possible to suppress implicit conversion from null on a struct with operator overloads?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, nullable

Normally, with value (struct) types, comparison with null (or object types) will result in a compiler error.

```
struct Value
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object o = new object();
        Value v = default;

        // Error CS0019  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Value' and '<null>'
        var a = v == null;

        // Error CS0019  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Value' and 'object'
        var b = v == o;
    }
}
```

However, if I add equality operator overloads on the struct, the comparison with null no longer produces a compiler error:

```
struct Value
{
    public static bool operator ==(Value l, Value r)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Value l, Value r)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object o = new object();
        Value v = default;

        // compiler is now happy with this.
        var a = v == null;

        // Error CS0019  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Value' and 'object'
        var b = v == o;
    }
}
```

I believe this has something to do with implicit conversion to `Nullable<Value>`, but I can't remember the details. The question is: Is it possible to overload these operators on a struct while preserving that compiler error?

I've refactored some code, and I think there are some landmines in the codebase due to this issue. I also worry that future code might accidentally be written in this form, and I'd really like it to produce a compiler error (Without having to implement an analyzer).

Comment: I was just reading in C# In Depth by Jon Skeet that things like this were now made possible with `Nullable<T>`, which could lead to weird things like this, and it involved operator overloading nullable types, called "lifted operators" and the implict conversions from `T?` to `T`, but for that to work, they had to allow `if (myInt == null)` even though `myInt` is a normal `int` and will never be `null`. That has to be there though, incase there was an implicit cast from `int?`. Unfortunately, that doesn't give me any clue on how to supress the implicit cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because compiler automatically generates so called lifted operators that also work with nullable values types as you can read in [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#lifted-operators). So for given comparison operator `T, U -> bool` where `T` and `U` are non-nullable value types there also exist lifted operators `T?, U -> bool`, `T, U? -> bool` and `T?, U? -> bool`.

To suppress those operators you can explicitly define them and decorate with an `Obsolete` attribute with `error` parameter set to `true` as follows:

```
struct Value
{
    public static bool operator ==(Value l, Value r)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Value l, Value r)
    {
        return true;
    }

    [Obsolete("Some error message", error: true)]
    public static bool operator ==(Value? l, Value r) => 
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    [Obsolete("Some error message", error: true)]
    public static bool operator ==(Value l, Value? r) => 
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    [Obsolete("Some error message", error: true)]
    public static bool operator ==(Value? l, Value? r) => 
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    [Obsolete("Some error message", error: true)]
    public static bool operator !=(Value? l, Value r) => 
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    [Obsolete("Some error message", error: true)]
    public static bool operator !=(Value l, Value? r) => 
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    [Obsolete("Some error message", error: true)]
    public static bool operator !=(Value? l, Value? r) => 
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Now in comparisons like `new Value() == null` and also `new Value() == (Value?)null` the above matching user-definied operator will be chosen because it's more specific and such error will be given:

> error CS0619: 'Value.operator ==(Value, Value?)' is obsolete: 'Some error message'

Comment: Perfect, and obvious solution; not sure why it didn't occur to me. A little obnoxious that you need to defined every combination of null/notnull, but so be it. In this particular case, I wish the compiler did a little less work on my behalf, but at least we can work around it. Thank you!